# Search on metadata

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-scope

SharePoint 2013, SQL server 2014.
My client wants to search on metadata.  In other words, I have metadata that captures document type (Memo, Letter, Report), Classification level (Secret, Confidential, Top secret) and then original Author (which is a text field, not the Create By field)
Is it possible that I can setup their search to search for example all documents in the sub site where Document type = "Memo" or where Classification level = "Secret"
If so, how would I be able to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You need create managed property map to metadata field, then run a full crawl.

For example:

[image]

You could check below official guideline.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-the-search-schema

Comment: Thank you Lee_MSFT, but how do I then search for all document types that are 'memos' or all classification levels that are 'secret'?

Comment: Use KQL "owstaxIdMyField:Memos" or "owstaxIdMyField=Memos" depending on your circumstance.